# PHP - how to set which printed info from file is the JSON response?

Tags: php, jquery, json, response

So, when i sent json it waits resonse and all what happends in the file where is sent the json is treat as response. How to set which echo/printed information, because there will be also other things than echoes/ exactly is the response? For example i have this code and i want to do something else than the resonse in this if:
PHP:

```
if($_POST){
    $return="Success.";
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit;
}
```

jQuery:

```
    $.ajax({
          url: "./index.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: { 
                example:"example",
                example2:$(".content").text()
          },
          dataType: "json"
   }).done(function(data){
          $('#response').append('<p style="color:red;">'+data+'</p>');
   }).fail(function(){
         $('#response').append('<p style="color:red;">Error</p>');
   });
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you want to access the values of `example:` and `example2:` ?

Comment: Yes i want to acces and save(may be and modify) the values of example and example 2 into file/db or something. And that not to be added to the response because it will fail it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand whats your problem.

But you have an bug and maybe because that you wouldnt get a json object in your javascript.

```
if($_POST){
    $return=array("Success.");
    echo json_encode($return);
    exit;
}
```

json_encode needs an array :)

Comment: I edited the question. If you don't understand it now i can't explain it simplier/cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

By default you will get a HTTP 200 Ok response,

I undestand that you are trying to send an **error**, under some conditions, so your ajax request goes through **fail function**.

You can achive this in php with this:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 500 Internal Server Error', true, 500);
```

Regards

Comment: No, i am not trying to do that. I added exactly what i am trying to do in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but its hard to understand you. Whats you mothertongue? German? (then write pastebin with german text please and send me)

You can do anything else than returning the success string.
For example writing each value to file e.g.

Building an array at the beginning and return it at the end.
Then you could add some things while your script is running.

I hope that helps :)

**index.php**

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $response = array();
    foreach($_POST as $file => $content)
    {
        $response[] = 'Writed ' .  file_put_contents($file, $content) . ' bytes to file ' . $file;
    }
    if(!count($response))
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
?><html>
<head>
    <title>25760456</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "./index.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    example:"example",
                    example2:$(".content").text()
                },
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function(data){
                $('#response').append('<p style="color:red;">'+data+'</p>');
            }).fail(function(){
                $('#response').append('<p style="color:red;">Error</p>');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #response {
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="content" />
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Looks like.

[image: example result in chrome webbrowser]